# What is the path to load a rake task for a new gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

I try to create a new rubygem with bundler and intent to load the rake task from rubygem folder ~/work/bezier/lib/task/. But the pwd seems to be in the /Users/wizztjh/work/bezier_server, what is the path to load a rake task for a new gem?

my rubygem folder

```
bezier/lib
  /railtie.rb
  /task/get_transitions.rake
```

pry

```
From: /Users/wizztjh/work/bezier/lib/bezier/railtie.rb @ line 4 :

    1: module Bezier
    2:   class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    3:     rake_tasks do
 => 4:       binding.pry
    5:       load "lib/task/get_transitions.rake"
    6:     end
    7:   end
    8: end

[1] pry(#<Bezier::Railtie>)> Dir.pwd
=> "/Users/wizztjh/work/bezier_server"
[2] pry(#<Bezier::Railtie>)>
```

Because according to rubygem documentation

```
rake_tasks do
    load "path/to/my_railtie.tasks"
end
```

but what is path/to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to use advance code search by github to search for `Rails::Railtie rake_tasks do load` [broadcast](https://github.com/futuresimple/broadcast/blob/3c469af6b212ea395939646410886c3b23631a6e/lib/broadcast/railtie.rb) and I found the solution.

bezier/tasks/get_transitions.rake

```
#bezier/lib/railtie.rb
module Bezier
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    railtie_name :bezier
    rake_tasks do 
       load "bezier/tasks/get_transitions.rake"
    end
  end
end
```

So, ruby gem railtie `load` pwd is the root of Gem.path

Answer (score 2):

A gem's `lib` directory is the root of the Railtie `rake_tasks` load path. So if your tasks are in `lib/tasks/stuff.rake`, use `load 'tasks/stuff.rake'`.

One such example is the [sitemap_generator gem](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/tree/master/lib).